# add a partial month to a date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a partial month to a date in oracle. i tried like this

```
SELECT months_between('1-DEC-2014',SYSDATE) FROM dual
```

i get  -2.79041218637993

then i tried to add (subtract) this result to sysdate.

```
SELECT add_months(trunc(SYSDATE), -2.79041218637993) FROM dual
```

i thought i should have gotten '1-DEC-2014' but it only added the 2 full months and left the .79041218637993 out so it returned 12/25/2014.

any ideas how i can get it to add the partial month as well so that it will return 12/01/2014?

Comment: how do you get that number? the decimal part refers to a month that have 30,28 or 31 days?How many days have 0.5: 15,14 or 15.5?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add_months` function:

```
select add_months(sysdate, 2) from dual;
```

**Edit :** To answer your comment, simply use

```
select sysdate + days_between('1-DEC-2014',SYSDATE) from dual;
```

Comment: i want to add 2.79041218637993 months. meaning, 2 months + .79041218637993 of a month (which should be 25 days in this case)

Comment: Then why not simply sysdate + 25 ?

Comment: because this is in a procedure and tomorrow it is going to be a different number of days and next week when i run it, it will be a different number of days so i want to figure it out without hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract 2 months and then trunc to month.

```
SELECT TRUNC(add_months(trunc(SYSDATE), -2),'MM') FROM dual
```